# Web app not working on iPhone - how to debug?

Tags: jquery, debugging, web-applications, iphone-web-app

I have created a web app. It is written in C# and asp.net but the majority of the functionality is written using jquery and jquery ajax.

It runs on safari browser for windows.

It does not run on iPhone.

It runs on Android.

I am trying to work out how can I debug what is wrong.  I could avail myself of an iPhone and remove everything from my web page - markup, css, javascript and reintroduce an element 1 at a time until it errors.

The problem is I do not have an iPhone at this present time.

The closet I got to debugging was to put a break point in my C# code in the page_load event to get the hardware/software details of the iPhone.

It is:

**Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D167 Safari/9537.53**

Is there a better way to debug a web app for iPhone as target and/or are there any glaring errors in my approach for designing a web app for iPhone compatibility to avoid without having a mac or iphone?

Comment: I don't know how well google chrome emulation works, but try this `F12 - > emulation tab -> Apple iPhone 5 -> Emulate` http://imgur.com/xWml8T3

Comment: Try this http://robandlauren.com/2013/09/14/test-on-devices/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your code written with C# in a PC or Mac? For PC I would suggest

https://www.genuitec.com/mobile/download.html

It allows you to test you project in all mobile platform on your computer.

another option is

http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/

Hope this  help.